# What is Document class in ace editor

Tags: embed, ace-editor

Hello guys what is Document in Ace editor I can't get it , am reading the documentation and it keep says Document class please explain here is an example

```
createEditSession(Document | String text, TextMode mode)
```

The Documentation is really poor and hard to understand can you suggest any source for learn how the ACE editor works and how can I embed it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document class is https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/document.js, normally you would call createEditSession with a string or array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation "At its core, Documents are just an array of strings, with each row in the document matching up to the array index.". 
  So a Document is "that thing" that you are editing in Ace editor. To create a new document:

```
var Document = require("ace/document").Document;
var doc = new Document("Lorem ipsum");
```

Then to edit that document in Ace:

```
var lorem_session = ace.createEditSession(doc);
my_ace_editor.setSession(lorem_session);
```